# Verificar se existe tag dentro de site

Tags: php

Faço a geração de uma tag especifica do meu sistema, meus clientes precisam adicionar essa tag dentro da `body`de suas index, meu problema é: Como identificar se essa tag está dentro do site, apenas pela sua url, sem informar o nome do arquivo, por exemplo:

O cliente informa sua url: `www.teste.com.br`, e meu sistema acessará e irá verificar se a tag está lá.

Atualmente eu gero um .html, o cliente faz o upload para sua hospedagem e meu sistema verifica se um determinado conteúdo existe naquele arquivo enviado:

```
    $file_download = "1__".md5('1').".html";
    $url = "http://www.site.com.br/".$file_download.";

    $arquivo = $url ;
    $handle = @fopen($arquivo, "rb");
    $cont = @fread($handle, 100);

    if($cont == "verifica-licenca") {
        echo 1;
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
```

Funcionando perfeitamente, mas, preciso da metodologia da tag, ou seja, o único problema é: Verificar se o conteúdo está na url principal, isso, sem informar o arquivo

Vlw

Comment: Essa sua tag esta no `body` da pagina principal?

Comment: Sim, a tag deverá ser inserida pelo cliente dentro da body da página principal

Comment: Como é o nome da sua tag?

Comment: Se puder adicionar detalhes ajudaria. Por exemplo, como é a tag e como está presente numa página "real".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom o código acredito que é bem simples. Primeiro você precisa do código fonte do site. que voce pode obter da seguinte forma:

```
$codigofonte=file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
```

Com o código fonte em mãos, fica simples para buscar sua tag, usei uma "expressão regular" para nesse caso `substituir`a sua tag, mas que na verdade só quero saber se ele substituiu, porque ai sei que a sua tag existe.

```
$result=preg_match_all($tag,$codigofonte,$valorsubstituido);
```

Nessa linha, a variavel `$result` tera como valor, `true` ou `false`, ou seja, se encontrou e substituiu ou não.

Segue o código:

```
<?php

// pega o codigo fonte do site
$codigofonte=file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");

//sua tag
$tag='/<minhatag>/';

// 'busca' sua tag no coigo
$result=preg_match_all($tag,$codigofonte,$valorsubstituido);

if(!$result){
    echo "nao encontrado";
} else {
    echo "encontrado";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Uma outra forma seria utilizando *[DOMDocument do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php)*, especialmente para quem não gosta de *REGEX*. :P

Pegue o código fonte:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://seu_site_alvo.com');
curl_setopt_array($ch, [

    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4,
    CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE => true,
    CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false

]);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

> *Você pode utilizar o `file_get_contents` ou `fopen` também.*

Então use o `DOM`:

```
// Inicia o DOM e XPath:
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$XPath = new DomXPath($DOM);

// Obtem a contagem de todos os `<a>` que possuem o `HREF` de `http://www.site.com.br` e também que contenham o `CLASS` de `authority`.
if($XPath->evaluate("//a[contains(@class, 'authority') and @href='http://www.site.com.br']")->length >= 1){

        echo 'Encontrado';

}
```

Dessa forma conseguirá saber, sem uso de REGEX, se contêm o HTML. O código acima também faz com que isto:

```
<a href="http://www.site.com.br" class="authority outra_coisa"></a>
```

Também seja válido. Caso não deseje isso, utilize o `@class='authority` ao invés do `contains(@class, 'authority')`, por exemplo.

Comment: O melhor caminho, se mudar a ordem dos atributos, o as letras estiverem em maiusculo no nome da tag, ainda sim irá funcionar bem +1

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado da seguinte forma

```
                    // pega o codigo fonte do site
                $codigofonte=file_get_contents('http://www.google.com.br');


                //sua tag
                $tag='<a href="http://www.site.com.br" id="authority"></a>';
                    // 'busca' sua tag no codigo
                if (stripos(strtolower($codigofonte), $tag) !== false){
                        //Encontrado
                        echo 1;
                    }
                    else{
                        //Não Encontrado
                        echo 0;
                    }
```