# Como fazer um "link format" (um sistema que leia o conteudo de outros sites webs)?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, facebook

Gostaria de integrar um sistema semelhante a do facebook pra leitura links externos no meu projeto.

Tipo ao publicar um link "www.un-site-qualquer.com" no meu site
gostaria de obter um resultado como da figura abaixo !

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua pergunta parece bastante ampla. Mas, só para ter certeza, você quer fazer um sistema que "leia" o conteúdo do outro website ou que o seu website seja mostrado desta forma no quando compartilhado no Facebook?

Comment: @Inkeliz um sistema que leia o conteudo de outros sites webs !

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar um cURL para isso e então usar o DOMDocument (ou REGEX) para obter os dados da página.

O Facebook utiliza o [Open Graph markup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup), uma vez que muitos websites suportam ele você pode também ler tais dados.

> Estou usando como exemplo o [`http://g1.globo.com/rj/sul-do-rio-costa-verde/noticia/2017/01/acidente-com-teori-zavascki-aviao-comeca-ser-retirado-do-mar.html`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fg1.globo.com%2Frj%2Fsul-do-rio-costa-verde%2Fnoticia%2F2017%2F01%2Facidente-com-teori-zavascki-aviao-comeca-ser-retirado-do-mar.html), que é a última noticia do Globo.com neste momento.

Você pode extrair desta página o meta `og:image` e o `og:title` e também o `og:description`. Além disso *todos* os websites possuem os `meta` padrões ou é esperado que se tenha o `description` e o `title`.

Por exemplo, *[usando como base uma resposta à outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178942/verificar-se-existe-tag-dentro-de-site/179016#179016):*

```
// Obtem o HTML da página
$ch = curl_init('http://g1.globo.com/rj/sul-do-rio-costa-verde/noticia/2017/01/acidente-com-teori-zavascki-aviao-comeca-ser-retirado-do-mar.html');
curl_setopt_array($ch, [    
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
    CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS,  
    CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 2
]);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Inicia o DOM e XPath:
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$XPath = new DomXPath($DOM);

// Propriedades buscadas
$propriedades = ['description', 'title', 'type', 'image'];

// Verifica cada item da Array:
foreach ($propriedades as $propriedade){

    $Meta = $XPath->query('//head//meta[(@property="og:'.$propriedade.'") or (@name="'.$propriedade.'")] | //head//'.$propriedade);

    // Se achar o elemento irá obter o resultado
    if($Meta->length !== 0){
        $conteudo[$propriedade] = $Meta->item(0)->getAttribute('content') !== '' ? $Meta->item(0)->getAttribute('content') : $Meta->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }


}
```

---

**Resultado:**

```
array(4) {
  ["description"]=>
  string(134) "Serviço de remoção aconteceu no início da noite deste domingo (22).
Retirada foi feita por empresa contratada pelo Grupo Emiliano."
  ["title"]=>
  string(73) "Acidente com Teori Zavascki: Avião que caiu em Paraty é retirado do mar"
  ["type"]=>
  string(7) "article"
  ["image"]=>
  string(122) "http://s2.glbimg.com/IAaOKflQpOoOSoi7pGNjkmirtjI=/1200x630/filters:max_age(3600)/s02.video.glbimg.com/deo/vi/65/44/5594465"
}
```

Com essas informações poderá montar o HTML como desejar.

---

**Explicações:**

> CURL:

O `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` é usado para seguir o `location:` caso isto seja informado pelo servidor, o `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` é necessário para obter o resultado, já o `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` e `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` foram desligados para que possa obter a informação mesmo num servidor que possua um certificado *self-signed* por exemplo. Você pode adicionar também timeout e um máximo de redirecionamento.

> XPATH:

É usado para buscar as informações a query:

```
//head//meta[(@property="og:'.$propriedade.'") or (@name="'.$propriedade.'")] | //head//'.$propriedade
```

Isto irá fazer com todas as situações abaixo sejam válidas:

```
<head>
<description>Valor</description>
<meta name="description" content="Valor" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Valor" />
</head>
```

Para verificar se houve alguma ocorrencia, se realmente existe algum dado, é utilizado:

```
$Meta->length !== 0
```

Como o conteúdo pode estar dentro do `content` (nos dois últimos exemplos) ou então dentro da própria tag (no primeiro exemplo), foi utilizado:

```
$conteudo[$propriedade] = $Meta->item(0)->getAttribute('content') !== '' ? $Meta->item(0)->getAttribute('content') : $Meta->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Isso irá verificar se existe o atributo `content`, na verdade irá verificar se há algum dado nele, se não irá obter o valor do elemento.