# Miniatura de Imagem através da URL

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Quero fazer assim:

Tem um campo onde o usuário insere a URL de uma imagem, e queria que ao colar esta url no campo, apareça uma miniatura ao lado (ou embaixo) do campo, parecido com o que o FB faz, onde vc cola a url do vídeo no post, e ele exibe a miniatura.

Comment: Ta, e ai? Qual sua duvida? :)
Poste um exemplo do que já tentou

Comment: Não tentei, apenas tem o input que o cara coloca a url, não sei por onde começar!

Comment: Acredito que deste modo fica difícil ajudar, entenda que esse tipo de pergunta é do tipo "façam tudo por mim", se possivel, leia: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas

Comment: Respondi uma questão parecida, pode ajudar, mas a mesma pergunta também foi fechada, veja em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/179198/como-fazer-um-link-format-um-sistema-que-leia-o-conteudo-de-outros-sites-webs/. Apesar de ser em PHP a lógica é a mesma.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio não quero que façam por mim, apenas que me dêem dicas sobre o assunto. Estou começando praticamente agora, mas só de dizer o que posso usar já é o suficiente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa o evento "paste" do Jquery para detectar o colar da url no campo e então recupere o valor e crie o elemento img com a imagem.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
  
    //ao colar a url no campo
    $("#url").bind('paste', function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
          
          var url = $("#url").val();
          var img = '<img src="'+url+'">';
          $(".img").append(img);
        
        }, 100);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

URL: <input type="text" name="url" id="url">

<p align="center">
  <div class="img"></div>
</p>
```

Comment: É mais ou menos isso que eu quero, assim que der vou testar. Obrigado

Comment: Show de bola Glauber!! Valeu